# New/updated element inherits event handlers from old one, D3

Tags: javascript, inheritance, d3.js

when I create circles in D3 i can assign them e.g. onclick events

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataArray).enter().append("circle").on("click"),function(d){// do stuff});
```

When I want to create new circles and therefore update the data set of my circles I do this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(newDataSet,function(d){return d;}).enter().append("circle")
```

(I left the attributes out on purpose)

Is there a way to somehow inherit the on() events from my old circles or do I have to define these events again?

From my understanding it shouldn't be possible, because d3 is not object orientated.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, the OP is making a genuine and adequate question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, below is not entirely correct. enter will just give you nodes for which there is no existing DOM element. You would use merge (in v4) to update the already existing nodes.

> When I want to create new circles and therefore update the data set of
> my circles I do this:
>
> ```
> svg.selectAll("circle").data(newDataSet,function(d){return d;}).enter().append("circle")
> ```

Coming to your actual question, below would assign click listener for each of the circle dom node.

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataArray).enter().append("circle").on("click", function(d){/* do stuff */});
```

So, new nodes added would have to assigned new event listeners.

I think you might be missing understanding of data joins, [this](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is an excellent read. Using data joins would look something like this:

```
function makeCircles(data) {
        var circles = d3.select('svg')
                .selectAll('circle')
                .data(data, function(d) {
                    return d;
                });

        circles.exit().remove();

        circles.enter()
                .append('circle')
                .merge(circles)
                .attr('r', function(d) {
                    return d + 5;
                })
                .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
                    return 50 + 50 * i;
                })
                .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
                    return 30;
                })
                .on('click', function() {
                    // do stuff
                })
    }

    var data = [1, 2, 3];
    makeCircles(data);
    data = [10, 15, 16];
    makeCircles(data);
```

If your concern is about assigning multiple event listeners, why not assign event listener to parent element of circles and let the events bubble?